# adding new site column is not working Field with name “xx” was not found

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

The scenario is that I am trying to add a new site column, I need to update the schema definition.
the 2nd time the update executes it says the field was not found, but its there, I can even see it on site columns after the feature activating crashes

```
private void AddManagerField(SPWeb currentweb)
        {
             try
            {
                //Add new field to Site Columns
                string managerFieldName = currentweb.Fields.Add(SponsoringCommon.Constants.FIELDS_SPONSORINGMANAGER_NAME, SPFieldType.User, false);
                SPFieldUser managerField = currentweb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(managerFieldName) as SPFieldUser;
                managerField.Group = SponsoringCommon.Constants.DEFAULT_TAXONOMY_TERMGROUP_NATIONALELOTERIJSPONSORING;
                managerField.Update();


                SPFieldUser managerField2 = currentweb.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(managerFieldName) as SPFieldUser;

                string schemaXmlWithResourceTokens = managerField2.SchemaXmlWithResourceTokens;
                int startIndex = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("\"", schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("DisplayName=\"")) + 1;
                int endIndex = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.IndexOf("\"", startIndex);
                int substringLength = endIndex - startIndex;
                string value = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Substring(startIndex, substringLength);
                schemaXmlWithResourceTokens = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens.Replace(value, "$Resources:SPNLSponsoring,Field_SponsoringManager_Name");
                managerField2.SchemaXml = schemaXmlWithResourceTokens;
                managerField2.Update();


                SPContentTypeId dossierCTID = new SPContentTypeId(SponsoringCommon.Constants.CONTENTTYPES_DOSSIER_ID);
                SPContentType dossierCT = currentweb.ContentTypes[dossierCTID];
                SPFieldLink managerFieldLink = new SPFieldLink(managerField2);
                dossierCT.FieldLinks.Add(managerFieldLink);
                dossierCT.Update(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError("error", "AddManagerField(SPWeb currentweb)", ex);
                throw;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the internal names are identical.

If you have access to the server try and get the GUID of the column and use that instead as this will guarantee you are looking for the correct field.

Is the field in the web you are passing in to this Method?

Sorry may seem simple but once i have sat down and been through my code (after debugging) i normally find i am being neglectful about chacking all the angles.

Hope this helps
     Truez